GPT Fine Tuning error says Key is missing, but its there
I am trying to submit a fine tuning job to OpenAI and keep getting this error message for function calls that do not have any arguments:
The job failed due to an invalid training file. Invalid file format. Example 38, message 2 is missing key "function_call".

this is the jsonl (expanded for readability) it errors out on.  Im not sure what i am missing:
{
 "messages": [
{
  "role": "user",
  "content": "start over"
},
{
  "role": "assistant",
  "function_call": {
    "name": "clear_gpt_session"
  }
}
],
"functions": [
{
  "name": "clear_gpt_session",
  "description": "Clears the current chat session for the user and allows them to start the conversation over."
}
]}

if i remove this line, it uploads and processes without any errors.
